# Error "please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google services plugin''a

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.6.**

According to me build.gradle versions are okay

build.gradle(module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.deepdepindersingh.mutual"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'UNIQUE_FIREBASE_ROOT_URL', UniqueFirebaseRootUrl
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'


    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.5.3'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'

    /* For Google Play Services */
    //compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:10.2.6'
   // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 10.2.6 for firebase in your dependencies
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'

and 9.6.1 for the rest
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'

You have to always use the same versions for google related stuff.
Change firebase auth and core also to 10.2.6

Comment: This support library should not use a lower version (25) than the targetSdkVersion (26) less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)

Comment: fixed target version downgraded to 25..but second error All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.3.1, 23.4.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and com.android.support:customtabs:23.4.0 less... (Ctrl+F1

Comment: It seems the customtabs gradle file needs to be changed from 23.4.0 to 25.3.1